# Google Apps Script - Convert base 64 Image source to an image file

Tags: image, file, google-apps-script, base64

Here is an example of an image tag with the image source as base 64 data.  The base 64 data is a smiley face.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAAAAAMAAwAAAMlWLPcGjDKFYi9lxKBOaGcF35DhWHamZUW0K4mAbiwWtuf0uxFAgA7">
```

I want to use base64 data to create an image file in Google Drive.

I've tried the following code, which runs, and creates a file with no errors, but it won't open as an image file.

```
function createImageFileFromBase64() {
  var data = 'R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAAAAAMAAwAAAMlWLPcGjDKFYi9lxKBOaGcF35DhWHamZUW0K4mAbiwWtuf0uxFAgA7';

  var imageBlob = Utilities.newBlob(data, 'image/png');

  var resource = {
    title: 'AAA Test_Image',
    mimeType: 'image/png'
  }

  var theReturn = Drive.Files.insert(resource,imageBlob );

  Logger.log('file ID: ' + theReturn.id);
}
```

My goal is to make an image file without making an external request to an image file.  I want the image data to be "hard coded" into the script.

Comment: You need to decode it into a byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the blob using byte array created by [decoding the base64](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64decodeencoded) string:

```
var imageBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), 'image/png');
```